# How can I use multiple values for Android XML Layout properties?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I feel like this must have been asked before, but I can't find it.

I want to have a `LinearLayout` such that everything aligns to the right as well as to the bottom.

I've tried:

```
    android:gravity="right | bottom"
    android:gravity="right + bottom"
    android:gravity="right & bottom"
    android:gravity="right, bottom"
    android:gravity="right bottom"
```

All of these produce

```
 Error: String types not allowed (at 'gravity' with value 'right, bottom').
```

I suppose I could use margins on the sub-elements, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Grah. It was the spaces. Correct syntax is

```
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
```

I wish Eclipse would have suggestions like that if it sees you're entering a string. Like

```
Error: String types not allowed (at 'gravity' with value 'right, bottom').
If you want to enter multiple values, use the syntax "value1|value2"
```

Comment: Awesome, I was looking for this answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's what I want, after by removing white space.

Comment: Reflecting on this quite a bit later, it occurs to me that the reference to String types not being allowed is probably because this is a integer, or in the case of `value1|value2`, two integer flags being combined with the `OR` operator. But it's still not clear why spaces ought make it die.